# Tag for Babel Language Interoperability Tool

Tags: support, tags

What tag should I use for [Babel Language Interoperability Tool](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/components/index.html#page=home)?

Comment: There does't seem to be one at the moment. [tag:babel] already exists for another purpose. Would something like [tag:babel-hpli] make sense?

Comment: Would babel-sidl make sense? Or babel-casc?

Comment: I'd probably go for [[tag:babel-code-generator]]+[[tag:SIDL]/[tag:XML]]+[target language]. Write it out if nothing else makes sense

Comment: @Bergi I think your suggestion makes the most sense. I'll accept it as an answer in a couple of days

Comment: @alex accepting comments as answer is generally not something that is possible ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing immediately jumps to the eye, spell it out. It's better the be explicit anyway, and acronyms or abbreviations have often enough failed as tag names (like [blit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blit) would here).

I'd therefore recommend to use [babel-code-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel-code-generator), alongside with the input format ([sidl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sidl) or [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml)) and the target language.